# Windows phone kids corner set or remove password

Tags: kids-corner

I have turned on Kid's corner. Now I want to remove password for kids corner screen. I have(**windows phone 8.1**) set password for my phone but it is also applying for kids corner screen. How can I remove password for kids corner? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. And I'm afraid answer on your question is no.

From [MS site](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/people/set-up-kids-corner):

> If your phone is set to lock itself automatically after a period of
>   inactivity, you might sometimes need to enter your lock screen
>   password before your child can open Kid's Corner.